# How can I copy transposed data from one sheet to another?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a command button on one sheet to take the data from multiple cell ranges and copy the data to another sheet in one horizontal row.

The data must be copied to the next empty row and carry down the same table formatting as it adds a new line each time.

The code I am using copies some of the data in a new row each time I click the command button and some of the data on the same line repeatedly.

```vb
Sub Submit()

Range("E6:E27").Copy

Sheets("JANUARY").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
  False, Transpose:=True

Range("D3").Copy

Sheets("JANUARY").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
  False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `D3 + E6:E27.Transposed` as a new row, in the first empty row of `Sheets("JANUARY")`. If that's the case your first empty cell in `Sheets("JANUARY").Column B` may not be aligned with `.Column F`

The code bellow finds the first empty row in `Sheets("JANUARY")` based on `.Column F` only, and uses it for both paste operations

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SubmitData()

    Const FORMAT_ROW = 2

    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet, lrTo As Long
    Dim eRng As Range, fRng As Range, fCols As Long

    Set wsFrom = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set wsTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JANUARY")

    lrTo = wsTo.Range("F" & wsTo.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Set eRng = wsFrom.Range("E6:E7")
    fCols = eRng.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    eRng.Copy
    wsTo.Cells(lrTo, 6).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True

    'Copy format for destination row (from the 2nd row on destination sheet)
    Set fRng = wsTo.Range(wsTo.Cells(FORMAT_ROW, 6), wsTo.Cells(FORMAT_ROW, 6))
    Set eRng = wsTo.Range(wsTo.Cells(lrTo, 6), wsTo.Cells(lrTo, 6 + fCols - 1))
    fRng.Copy
    eRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

    wsFrom.Range("D3").Copy
    wsTo.Cells(lrTo, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Copy format for destination cell (from the 2nd row on destination sheet)
    wsTo.Cells(FORMAT_ROW, 2).Copy
    wsTo.Cells(lrTo, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Comment: I apologize for the delayed response, but thank you so much for your reply as this has helped tremendously and it works! I had made several attempts at setting the ws names to refer to however I see the mistake I initially made was using Set wsFrom and wsTo. Thank you for the great advise. I do have one more question though if you can assist?? How can I keep the same formatting of the destination sheet when I copy the information over? Right now it is just copying the values, but I would like for it to bring the prior row formatting down with each paste. I hope that makes sense! Thanks again!

Comment: I made a change that will copy the destination formats (not the values) from the second row on the destination sheet, to the new row just copied

Comment: That was perfect! I just went in and added some additional cells I needed copied over as well but it all works like a charm now. Thank you so much for all of your assistance. I have spent days on getting this right already lol but I am learning.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)